# Attempting to sort an array of structs in c using the return value of ctime from a call to stat

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I'm attempting to sort a directory listing based on the most recent st_mtime, and having trouble figuring out how exactly to sort the struct array I'm allocating. How can I sort the struct according to the most recent date?... here's my current approach:

```
static int cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2){

   return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
}


 struct directoryStat dStat{
      char name[50];
      char time[50];

    };

    int main(){

       i = 0;
       while ((ep = readdir(dp))){

          stat(ep->d_name, &fileStat); 
          strcpy(dStat[i].name, ep->d_name);
          strcpy(dStat[i].time, ctime(&fileStat.st_mtime));
          i++;

       }
    }

qsort(dStat, i, sizeof(char), cmpstringp);
```

Comment: Since the 2.6 kernel, `stat` provides both `struct timespec st_ctim;` and `#define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec` either of which could be used directly in a numeric sort of the results. The call to `ctime` returns a string of the form `"Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"` (see: *man ctime*) which does not appear to be what you want.

Comment: Your comparison routine could convert the time string back to a binary format using `strptime` if supported. However, some time strings will be ambiguous for periods when the clocks go back at the end of DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting time (or datetime)-values based on their string representations might not be a good idea, because this (lexicographical) order based on a probably localization-dependent string representation of a date/time-value might then not correspond to the chronological order (cf., for example, David C. Rankin's comment). I'd store and compare the raw `time_t`-values instead.

See the following code, which demonstrates both, sorting by a string value and sorting by a `time_t`-value. Hope it helps!

```
typedef struct directoryStat  {
    char name[50];
    char timeStr[50];
    time_t timeVal;
}dStat;


int cmpDStatTimeStr(const void *p1, const void *p2){

    return strcmp( ((dStat*)p1)->timeStr, ((dStat*)p2)->timeStr);
}

int cmpDStatTimeVal(const void *p1, const void *p2){

    return ((dStat*)p1)->timeVal > ((dStat*)p2)->timeVal;
}

int main(){

    dStat stat[2] = { { "the former", "2017/5/2", 14500000 },  { "the latter","2017/5/12", 14500001 }};

    // sort based on string value (lexigraphical comparison):
    qsort(stat, 2, sizeof(dStat), cmpDStatTimeStr);

    // sort based on time value directly:
    qsort(stat, 2, sizeof(dStat), cmpDStatTimeVal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. i guess it may have been a silly approach to reduce the time_t value to a string and sort it that way, but thank you for demonstrating both methods.